# popToRootViewControllerAnimated makes my application crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8

My application contains some `UIViewControllers`. The first one is a login page, the second one a "Menu page" and a third `viewController`.

I put a logout function on a button on each pages, with an alertView like this :

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *logoutConfirm = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Logout" message: @"Sure ? " delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];

    [logoutConfirm show];
}

// Logout 
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Logs to track the bug
    NSLog(@"LOG :%@", [self.navigationController viewControllers]);
    NSLog(@" LOG 2 : %@", [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]);

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

The `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` makes crash the Application on the third `ViewController` but not the second with this message :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'adding a root view controller <MainViewController: 0xXXXXXX> as a child of view controller:<UINavigationController: 0xXXXXXX>'
```

There are my logs:

```
2014-09-25 10:24:35.074 Poject[18594:654203] LOG :(
    "<MainViewController: 0xXXXXXXX>",
    "<secondViewController: 0xXXXXXXX>",
    "<thirdViewController: 0xXXXXXXX>"
)
2014-09-25 10:24:35.075 Poject[18594:654203]  LOG 2 : <MainViewController: 0xXXXXXXX>
```

Seems I'm adding an `UIViewController`, but just wanted to back to the 1st viewController ... I think it's weird if it's work on the second ViewController but not the third ...

**UPDATE**

@mehul patel told me to comment this line in my AppDelegate.h :

```
[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

Because :

> You can not add your rootViewController as subview to window, it will crash in any way

But now, pushViewController on the "login button" in my firstViewController doesn't work anymore. It does nothing, so I NSLog the controllers array of my navigationController

First time I got :

```
2014-09-25 16:48:07.512 Project[22023:780717] (
    "<MainViewController: 0xf81f290>"
)
```

Second time I got :

```
2014-09-25 16:48:12.104 Project[22023:780717] (
    "<MainViewController: 0xf81f290>",
    "<MenuSelectionViewController: 0xd929030>"
)
```

But, the view doesn't change ...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you're using pushViewController: always right ?

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes I am : [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

Comment: @Ritooon: try to call popToRootViewControllerAnimated with a delay. that may help.

Comment: @Deepak Tried it, but didn't change anything

Comment: @Ritooon: it seems you are not using NavigationController properly. Which class is your rootViewController?

Comment: @Deepak, My rootViewController is this one : MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil]; And then :  self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

```
- (void) logout {

    @try {
        NSArray *controllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

        if (controllers && [controllers count] > 0) {
            UIViewController *loginController = [controllers objectAtIndex:0];
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:loginController animated:YES];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
            // Throws an exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, I put a NSLog in the "if" condition and one in the @catch, and I got the 2 logs ... Weird no ?

Comment: Put this line in exception block, Let me know which exception is raised:

NSLog(@"exception description :%@",exception.debugDescription);

Comment: I got this exception : exception description :adding a root view controller <MainViewController: 0x7ae69ec0> as a child of view controller:<UINavigationController: 0x7ab6d270>

Comment: You are using xibs, Right? If you are using it, then please check your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` that you are not adding rootViewController to window as a subview.

Comment: In which file ? I haven't implemented this function in my viewControllers

Comment: You will find this method in `AppDelegate.m` file. But if you are using `Storyboard` then it is not required to add code in this method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61906/discussion-between-mehul-patel-and-ritooon).

Answer (score 0):

We had quite old piece of code in `AppDelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController;
[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

Those two lines had to be removed and we added:

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

This solves the problem and it works for iOS7 and iOS8.

Comment: I'll try this solution. And will give you a feedback soon.